# Advanced CustInvoiceJournal

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I want to make a special CustInvoiceJournal. In a normal custinvoicejournal we have a list of salesorders and which invoiceId they are refering to. 
But some invoices contains of more than 1 salesorders. And we can see all the salesorders in the "lines" of the invoice.

My question is, how can I make a cust invoice journal, where I can see **ALL** the salesorders and invoiceid's etc.

Comment: I would start off by using a [SELECT DISTINCT statement](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/msdynamicsax2009abdelahmed/archive/2012/05/17/how-to-select-distinct-using-x) as the base of your form query, on the SalesId field across the 'CustInvoiceTrans' lines.

Comment: Could you describe your "advanced" journal with data examples?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that if I use CustInvoiceTrans as datasource, it will solve my problem. I needed to show every saleslines, and I wanted to be able to see if an invoice contains more than one salesorder. With the field OriginalSalesId I can see it